# How do I set TTL and catch exceptions when using op-rabbit?

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, akka

I have some `op-rabbit` code that looks like this:

```
val subscriptionRef: SubscriptionRef = Subscription.run(rabbitControl) {
  val directive = body(UTF8StringMarshaller) & routingKey
  channel(qos = MAX_CONCURRENT_MSGS) {
    consume(topic(queue(inputQueue), List(inputKey))) {
      directive((s, key) => {
        processMessage(s, key)
        ack
      })
    }
  }
}
```

It runs fine in some applications, but in my latest application, I got 5GB of errors in logs in just a few minutes.  I'm trying to figure out where to handle exceptions.  The cause of the error appears to be a mismatch in the queue's TTL (30 mins. or 1800000 ms), and what the application is expecting (apparently nothing).  I want to specify the TTL, and if there is a problem, I want to log it and then shutdown immediately.  I do not want to have a filesystem filled with stack traces like this:

```
18:39:08.518 [such-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] ERROR com.spingo.op_rabbit.SubscriptionActor - Connection related error while trying to re-bind a consumer to EXCHANGE.QUEUE. Waiting in anticipating of a new channel.
java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:123) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:948) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:50) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.spingo.op_rabbit.QueueConcrete.declare(Queue.scala:31) ~[op-rabbit-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.spingo.op_rabbit.Binding$$anon$2.declare(Binding.scala:79) ~[op-rabbit-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.spingo.op_rabbit.SubscriptionActor.doSubscribe(SubscriptionActor.scala:222) ~[op-rabbit-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.spingo.op_rabbit.SubscriptionActor$$anonfun$8.applyOrElse(SubscriptionActor.scala:170) ~[op-rabbit-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.spingo.op_rabbit.SubscriptionActor$$anonfun$8.applyOrElse(SubscriptionActor.scala:157) ~[op-rabbit-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:34) ~[scala-library-2.12.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.FSM.$anonfun$handleTransition$1(FSM.scala:608) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.FSM.$anonfun$handleTransition$1$adapted(FSM.scala:608) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389) ~[scala-library-2.12.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.FSM.handleTransition(FSM.scala:608) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.FSM.makeTransition(FSM.scala:690) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.FSM.makeTransition$(FSM.scala:683) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at com.spingo.op_rabbit.SubscriptionActor.makeTransition(SubscriptionActor.scala:11) ~[op-rabbit-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at akka.actor.FSM.applyState(FSM.scala:675) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.FSM.applyState$(FSM.scala:673) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at com.spingo.op_rabbit.SubscriptionActor.applyState(SubscriptionActor.scala:11) ~[op-rabbit-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at akka.actor.FSM.processEvent(FSM.scala:670) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.FSM.processEvent$(FSM.scala:662) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at com.spingo.op_rabbit.SubscriptionActor.akka$actor$LoggingFSM$$super$processEvent(SubscriptionActor.scala:11) ~[op-rabbit-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at akka.actor.LoggingFSM.processEvent(FSM.scala:801) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.LoggingFSM.processEvent$(FSM.scala:783) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at com.spingo.op_rabbit.SubscriptionActor.processEvent(SubscriptionActor.scala:11) ~[op-rabbit-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at akka.actor.FSM.akka$actor$FSM$$processMsg(FSM.scala:659) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.FSM$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(FSM.scala:653) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:514) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:512) ~[akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at com.spingo.op_rabbit.SubscriptionActor.aroundReceive(SubscriptionActor.scala:11) ~[op-rabbit-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527) [akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496) [akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257) [akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224) [akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234) [akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [akka-actor_2.12-2.5.4.jar:?]
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-message-ttl' for queue 'EXCHANGE.QUEUE' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value '1800000' of type 'long', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:229) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:117) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-message-ttl' for queue 'EXCHANGE.QUEUE' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value '1800000' of type 'long', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:505) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:336) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:143) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:634) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572) ~[amqp-client-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
18:39:08.534 [such-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] ERROR com.spingo.op_rabbit.SubscriptionActor - Connection related error while trying to re-bind a consumer to EXCHANGE.QUEUE. Waiting in anticipating of a new channel.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to re-declare the queue using a value of `x-message-ttl` of zero. Delete the queue first, then it can be declared with whatever your code would like.

> channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-message-ttl' for queue 'EXCHANGE.QUEUE' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value '1800000' of type 'long', class-id=50, method-id=10

To be completely clear, this is the **per-message TTL**, not the per-queue TTL. There is a difference and that might be your issue.

Otherwise, the code is going to keep trying to do the same thing, and the broker is going to continue to reject the operation.

Comment: Thanks.  The queue already exists, and it has a per-msg TTL of 1800000.  The queue is set up the way the queue admins want it set up.  My code did not specify the TTL, so I figured it was my bad for not specifying the TTL when I set up the subscription, as I did with code prior to using op-rabbit.  I'm puzzled how the same kind of op-rabbit code I wrote (for other applications) worked fine, when I did not specify the TTL, but the queue had a per-message TTL.  I'm also puzzled how to catch exceptions. In an operational context, I can't have 5GB of errors in 15 mins.

Comment: That’s not something I can help with unfortunately. But I can say that if you re-declare a queue, it has to be done exactly the same way or it will result in channel closure. My recommendation is to not redeclare the queue.